# Mobilefirst 8 Swagger button

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am working on Mobilefirst platform 8 and i have a issue. Issue is that the swagger button is not visible on of my environmnent. I am a attaching two environment , one with swagger button (SIT) and another without swagger button (DEV).

[With Swagger button - SIT Enironment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oZwa.png)

[Without Swagger button - DEV Environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1d8c.png)

Please check the images and help me making the swagger doc button visible.

Comment: what is the Application server used?

Comment: Websphere Liberty 8.5.5.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In server.xml file in the Liberty server, Please check for and add the following lines

```
  <application context-root="doc" id="swagger-ui" location="mfp-server-swagger-ui.war" name="swagger-ui" type="war"/>


<!-- JNDI for the swagger ui, so the admin console can present a link to open the adapter information in the swagger ui -->
<jndiEntry jndiName="mfpadmin/mfp.server.swagger.ui.url" value="/doc/?url=/&lt;context&gt;/api/adapterdoc/&lt;adapterName&gt;"/>
```

Then restart the server.

Comment: Where do we find server.xml file?

Comment: The path will be like this  ../../Liberty/usr/servers/ServerName/server.xml. If it is helpful please give a upvote